# c3 categories tick formatting

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I have a c3 bar graphing categories. I'd like to format the category label to be able to truncate it to a certain length. But i can't figure it out.

Here is the graph definition:

```js
var chart;
chart = c3.generate({
                    padding: {
                        top: 20,
                        bottom: 20

                    },
                    data: {

                        columns: [
                                  ["Listeners",4,2,0],
                                  ["Listens",4,2,0]],
                        type: 'bar',
                        groups:[["Listeners", "Listens"]]
                    },
                    axis: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'category',
                            categories: ["012345678890", "012345678890", "012345678890"],
                            
                        }
                    },
                    bar: {
                        width: {
                            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false
                    }
                });
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/c3js/c3/0.4.11/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/c3js/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>

<div id="chart" class="c3" style="max-height: 280px; position: relative;"></div>
```

I tried adding this to format the tick inside the x axis definition, but it complains that chart is not defined

> tick:{format:function (x) { return chart.categories()[x].substring(0, 10); }}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you just declare the variable `var chart;` that has no value, is undefined.
Try to create the chart config before the function `c3.generate()` then pass the config as argument.

```
var config = {
        padding : {
            top : 20,
            bottom : 20
        },
        data : {
            columns : [ [ "Listeners", 4, 2, 0 ], [ "Listens", 4, 2, 0 ] ],
            type : 'bar',
            groups : [ [ "Listeners", "Listens" ] ]
        },
        axis : {
            x : {
                type: 'category',
                categories: ["012345678890", "012345678890","012345678890"],
            }
        },
        bar : {
            width : {
                ratio : 0.5
            }
        },
        legend : {
            show : false
        }
    };

    config.axis.x.tick = {
        format : function(x) {
            return config.axis.x.categories[x].substring(0,10)
        }
    };

    var chart = c3.generate(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have named categories in the x-axis definition, I'm not sure why you wouldn't just change the labels?

** EXAMPLE **

```js
var chart;
chart = c3.generate({
                    padding: {
                        top: 20,
                        bottom: 20

                    },
                    data: {

                        columns: [
                                  ["Listeners",4,2,0],
                                  ["Listens",4,2,0]],
                        type: 'bar',
                        groups:[["Listeners", "Listens"]]
                    },
                    axis: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'category',
                            _comment: "THIS IS WHERE YOU SET YOUR CATEGORY LABELS",
                            categories: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3"],
                            
                        }
                    },
                    bar: {
                        width: {
                            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: false
                    }
                });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart" class="c3" style="max-height: 280px; position: relative;"></div>
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion: 
                    axis: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'category',
                            label: ["012345678890", "012345678890", "012345678890"],
                            
                        }
                    } But that did not work

Comment: My problem is that i need to keep the category label long as they are also used for the tooltip, but truncate them for the display in the tick. So this solution does not work for me:-( @Dan